# my lists are not aligning properly and not sure how to fix

Tags: css, html-lists

i have a list that looks like this and i'm not putting any css into it but its not aligning to the bullet after it wraps on the second line...

template:

```
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus possimus maxime at repudiandae ut ad hic eaque cum fugiat ipsa odit natus, alias unde debitis explicabo, iste reiciendis dignissimos sequi.
                </li>
                <li>
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus possimus maxime at repudiandae ut ad hic eaque cum fugiat ipsa odit natus, alias unde debitis explicabo, iste reiciendis dignissimos sequi.
                </li>
                <li>
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus possimus maxime at repudiandae ut ad hic eaque cum fugiat ipsa odit natus, alias unde debitis explicabo, iste reiciendis dignissimos sequi.
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Output:

[image]

I want each of the lists to align to the bullet is there a way to do that with css?

Comment: Is there any extra css in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list-style-position: outset`:

```css
li {list-style-position: outset}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus possimus maxime at repudiandae ut ad hic eaque cum fugiat ipsa odit natus, alias unde debitis explicabo, iste reiciendis dignissimos sequi.
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus possimus maxime at repudiandae ut ad hic eaque cum fugiat ipsa odit natus, alias unde debitis explicabo, iste reiciendis dignissimos sequi.
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus possimus maxime at repudiandae ut ad hic eaque cum fugiat ipsa odit natus, alias unde debitis explicabo, iste reiciendis dignissimos sequi.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its still indenting the 2nd line...seems like the lists are put in quotations and that cuases the 2nd line to indent